# Can a vector in spherical co-ordinates have a radius of 0.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, electromagnetism

if so, what does that mean and can it be represented in Cartesian.

for example if I have a vector of in spherical
$$ \vec{A} =0\hat{\rho} + 2\hat{\theta} + 0\hat{\phi} $$

can $\vec{A}$ be represented in cartesian?

Comment: Isn't it just $\vec{0}$?

Comment: it's the point $(0,0,0)$ in cartesian.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the zero vector $\vec{0} = (0,0,0)^{T}$.